# Add new member to a variable in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to append new member to element which is in an array. Without array it's simple to write. for example:

```
$exp["app_form_id"] = $form_id;
```

But when I want add new member 'app_form_id' to all object of an array it not insert them and also there's not any error  with them. I tried do it by 2 way, but none of them not worked:

1)

```
foreach ($exps as $exp) {
        $exp["app_form_id"] = $form_id;
    }
```

2)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($exps); $i++) {
        $exps[i]["app_form_id"] = $form_id;
    }
```

Comment: Is $exp is object ??

Comment: Can you post, errors if there are any ? and update your question

Comment: $exps is an array which I get from $_POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your #1 method will work if you pass [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) (`&`):

```
foreach ($exps as &$exp) {
    $exp["app_form_id"] = $form_id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. So my problem was by ref types here.

Comment: If you don't need to keep base array as it is, its great answer.

Comment: @Rishi Yes. I think this's better answer. Thank you too

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are changing inside block is limited to the block and not changing back, Try like this

```
$newExps =  array();
foreach ($exps as $exp) {
    $exp["app_form_id"] = $form_id;
    $newExps[] = $exp;
}
print_r($newExps);
```

Comment: Your changes is limited to foreach block, @BizzyBob Answer would also work.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
foreach ($exps as &$exp) {
        $exp->app_form_id = $form_id;
}
```

I feel you are having manipulation with an object.

Give it a try, it should work.

Comment: I didn't consider `&$exp` in your answer. Your answer id correct too. Thanks.